# difference between Strings in C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, string

In `C++` I can do something like this...

```
String s = "abc";
char c = s[i]; // works fine...
```

But in `Java`, if I try doing the same, it throws an error. Why?.

In `java`, to achieve the above, I have to do :

```
s.toCharArray();
```

How is the implementation of Strings in `C++` different from that in Java?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> In java, to achieve the above, I have to do :
>       s.toCharArray();

Not really. You can use [`charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) instead:

```
char c = s.charAt(i);
```

Basically, C++ allows user-defined operators - Java doesn't. So the `String` class doesn't expose any sort of "indexing" operator; that *only* exists for arrays, and a `String` isn't an array. (It's usually *implemented* using an array, but that's a different matter.)

EDIT: As noted in comments, the `+` operator *is* special-cased for strings - right in the language specification. The same *could* have been done for `[]`, but it isn't - and as it's not in the language specification, and Java doesn't support overloaded operators, it can't be performed in library code. (For example, you can't give custom behaviour to `+` for any other class.)

Comment: You mean to say its because of operator overloading??

Comment: @X86: Yes, exactly. Rather than asking why Java *doesn't* allow `s[i]`, you should be asking yourself what makes it valid in C++.

Comment: Of course, Java _does_ have `s + s` just like C++. If `String` is being treated as a special case, defining `s[i]` is just as reasonable.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, `+` has special meaning for strings, but that's all. I'll make a note of that in the answer.

Comment: Perhaps that's the most important difference right there: In C++, `std::string` has no special status whatsoever. It's just a class from the standard library. It uses language features including operator overloading, but those same features are available to all. In particular, you can create an identical class yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that C++ has operator overloading, and uses it to access the string contents.

They both store the string characters in such a way as you cannot change them.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that it is possible to write

```
string s = "abc";
char c = s[i];
```

in C++ is that the `string` class has overloaded the indexing operator (say [] operator) which allows programmers to access characters of a `string` object the same way that they access an element of an array, despite the fact that a `string` object is not an array.

Java, on the other hand, does not allow operator overloading of any kind (the only exception is the `+` operator that is overloaded for strings) and hence, the indexing operator is not and can not be overloaded for `String` objects. In Java, to access a character of a string, you need to use accessor member methods, such as `charAt`. You can also invoke the `toCharArray` method of the `String` class, which returns to you an array of the characters of the string object and you can use the indexing operator with this returned value:

```
char c = s.toCharArray()[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

See the method [String#charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

> Returns the char value at the specified index. An index ranges from 0 to length() - 1. The first char value of the sequence is at index 0, the next at index 1, and so on, as for array indexing.
>
> If the char value specified by the index is a surrogate, the surrogate value is returned.

```
public char charAt(int index)
```

Comment: My question is why doesn't java allow str[i]

Comment: `In java, to achieve the above, I have to do  toCharArray:` No need.That is what i said.And I never compare two languages,In the end answer will be because they  both are different languages.

Comment: IMHO, this doesn't answer the OPs question at all!

Answer (score 0):

in c++ strings are already treated as array of characters,
but in java String is a built in class.
it is different from array of characters.

Comment: In C++, `std::string` is not an array of characters. E.g. it has a `size()` member, which `char[]` lacks. String _literals_ are arrays of characters. E.g. `"hello"` is a `char[6]`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, a string is typically just an array of (or a pointer to) chars, terminated with a NULL (\0) character. You can process a string by indexing also as you would process any array.
But in Java , a strings are not arrays. Java strings are objects of type `java.lang.String` so  You cannot process them by indexing .